# How to set attribute values as edges between nodes in Kibana Graph?

Tags: graph, kibana

I'm trying to connect some data within my Kibana-Graph.
I've got documents inside my ELK stack with the following structure:

> {"type": "external", "prev": "other-external", "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"", "timestamp": "2019-01-23T09:25:43.511Z", "n": 43}

Now the prev and curr attributes describe previous and current page views, meaning where is the user coming from and where is he/she now. "n" describes the connection frequency, meaning how often was this the case that somebody from an "other-external" link (like in the example) visited "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"" page.

My problem is that when I try to visualize the data, I cannot get the "n" to represent the connections between the prev and curr attributes.

Here are the nodes with a filter "prev=other":
[image: only nodes]

But when I add "n", it makes "n" as extra nodes (of course):
[image: nodes with n]

But how can I tell Kibana to use "n" as the connections between the correct nodes?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this link (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/graph-bar-chart-without-aggregation/134752), they say that it's not possible to use "raw" values yet, so I rewrote my "n" in "n times the document" and imported (curled) the data once more, but now with "n" indicating the id (notice that Elasticsearch already has an id, but I wanted to count my data, so I needed another index).

So I got  from:

> {"type": "external", "prev": "other-external", "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"", "timestamp": "2019-01-23T09:25:43.511Z", "n": 43}

to:

> {"type": "external", "prev": "other-external", "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"", "timestamp": "2019-01-23T09:25:43.511Z", "n": 1}
>
> {"type": "external", "prev": "other-external", "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"", "timestamp": "2019-01-23T09:25:43.511Z", "n": 2}
>
> {"type": "external", "prev": "other-external", "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"", "timestamp": "2019-01-23T09:25:43.511Z", "n": 3}
>
> {"type": "external", "prev": "other-external", "curr": "Ohio_\"Heartbeat_Bill\"", "timestamp": "2019-01-23T09:25:43.511Z", "n": 4}
>   ...

And now I can see the connections as I wanted them to be :)
Hope this helps somebody with the same problem.